AWS Cognito app client creation not setting up identity providers properly
I'm trying to create an app client for my Cognito user pool, using the following snippet of code:
CreateUserPoolClientRequest request = CreateUserPoolClientRequest.builder()
                        .clientName(clientName)
                        .userPoolId(userPoolId)
                        .generateSecret(true)
                        .allowedOAuthFlows(OAuthFlowType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                        .readAttributes("custom:proprietary_id")
                        .writeAttributes(List.of("family_name", "given_name", "name"))
                        .explicitAuthFlows(ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH)
                        .allowedOAuthScopes(allowedOAuthScopes)
                        .supportedIdentityProviders("COGNITO")
                        .build();
    
    CreateUserPoolClientResponse response = cognitoClient.createUserPoolClient(request);

As I go to the Cognito web interface, everything looks pristine, yet I cannot seem to make my ingestion calls work with the client secret used as token. As I found out, when I go to the web ui through

Hosted UI > Identity providers

and delete the supported identity providers set through the java request and just put them up again through the ui, my ingestion calls work flawlessy.
Is there anything missing in the code that breaks the app client?
